# Git clone to any server? (even without git installed)

Tags: git

I've googled and searched stackoverflow quite a bit, so I hope this hasn't been asked and I just missed it.

Can you clone a repository to any server/storage that you have access too? Or does this 'server' need to run git. As I understand it, it is enough that just the computer sending the commands has git?

Silly question, but started git today :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to clone into any folder structure, local or remote, to which you have access.  This doesn't depend on git being installed on the target server.  For example this is how I would clone a project into a Windows UNC share.

```
git clone git@github.com:whatever //server/share/target
```

I'm not entirely sure if that's what you mean though by "clone to any server".  If not could you be a bit more specific with your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use git over "dumb" Webdav (without any git code on the server side). In fact, I think you need to copy the repo manually once, then you can write to it.